# TableView no muestra correctamente los datos

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

Tengo un tableview que tiene que mostrar un intervalo de horas, y para ello tengo el siguiente código:

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
 listaObservable = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
 this.columnHora.setCellValueFactory(ListaItem->new SimpleStringProperty(item.getHora().toString()));
}
private void manageListHoras(){
        
        for(int i = 9; i <= 21; i++){
            LocalTime hora = LocalTime.of(i, 00);
            //System.out.println(hora.toString());
            item = new ListaItem(hora);
            listaObservable.add(item.getHora());
            System.out.println(listaObservable.toString());
            
        }
        tablaHorario.setItems(listaObservable);
  
        
    }
```

El objetivo es que muestre las horas del intervalo 9:00 - 21:00, para ello tengo una lista observable que contiene todos los datos y una clase ListaItem que representa un Item del ListView.
El atributo a representar es de tipo LocalTime. El bucle lo uso para añadir todas las horas a la lista observable y luego la muestro con:

```
tablaHorario.setItems(listaObservable);
```

Sin embargo, obtengo esto en el resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Curiosamente, en la consola obtengo que la lista observable funciona correctamente y almacena bien los datos:

```
[09:00]
[09:00, 10:00]
[09:00, 10:00, 11:00]
[09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00]
[09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00]
[09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00]
[09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00]
[09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00]
[09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00]
[09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00]
[09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00, 19:00]
[09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00, 19:00, 20:00]
[09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00, 19:00, 20:00, 21:00]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El detalle de los TableView es que tienen una estructura que se debe cumplir.

1. Crea en SceneBuilder tu FXML con la tabla y sus columnas
2. Luego crea una clase con los nombres de la columna

   ```
   public class FormatoPrototipo {
    private int id;
    // puedes agregar tantas variables como necesites
    // agregar los Getters y Setters

   }
   ```
3. En el controlador agrega las variables asociadas a la tabla, registros y columnas

   ```
   private ObservableList<FormatoPrototipo > seleccionadoRegistros; 
   // Registros para agregar dinamicamente
   @FXML
   private TableView<FormatoPrototipo > seleccionados; // nombre de la tabla
   @FXML
   private TableColumn<FormatoPrototipo , Integer> identificador; // columna id
   ```
4. Luego toca inicializar las variables en el inicializador del controlador

   ```
   seleccionadoRegistros = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); // registro
   seleccionados.setItems(seleccionadoRegistros); // acoplando tabla y registro

   seleccionadosCodigo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id")); // inicializando columna con la data que va en la variable id
   ```
5. Ahora lo que queda es agregar informacion al registro

   ```
   FormatoPrototipo fp = new FormatoPrototipo();
   fp.setId(24);
   seleccionadoRegistros.add(fp);
   ```

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar [answer] y [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Comment: Nunca he usado ChatGPT, siempre soy organizado para programar y documento bastante CODE CLEAN  el cual aplico en cualquier proyecto.